# showAsAction = "always" is ignored in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-xml, android-appcompat, android-menu, android-toolbar

After switching to toolbar there is a problem with menu icons. Although I set for a menu item android:showAsAction="always" it does not show the icon, I can only find it clicking on the popup icon.

This is myActivity

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  .........
  public void onCreate(....){
     .............
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(....); 
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }
  ............
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu{
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
  .............
}
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item
       android:id="@+id/settings"
       android:icon="@drawable/settings" 
       android:title="settings"
       android:showAsAction="always"
     />
    <item
       android:id="@+id/help"
       android:icon="@drawable/help" 
       android:title="help"
       android:showAsAction="never"
     />
</menu>
```

Both settings and help icons are only in popup menu. So how to show settings icon on toolbar?

Comment: Answer by CommonsWare is good but don't forget to set toolbar as a support action bar setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace `android:showAsAction` with `app:showAsAction`. You will also need to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` alongside your existing `xmlns` item in your root element.

Answer (score 1):

With AppCompat there is a little change. If you are running lint it will complain about it. Type this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/someId"
    android:title="@string/someText"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

You need to declare the "app" namespace and reference it.